# How to add other filters criteria to a jquery script

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this jquery script to filter data by periods in between dates. Now I need add one more fielter criteria to it but I don't know jquery. Truly I would prefer to do this by using a plain vanilla javascript as I understand it better.

The second fielter criteria would by the "POSITION" column.

```js
function filterRowsRelatorioPorItemTable() {

  var from = $('#datefilterfromRelatorioPorItemTable').val();
  var to = $('#datefiltertoRelatorioPorItemTable').val();
  

  if (!from && !to) { // no value for from and to
    return;
 
  }

  from = from || '2020-01-01'; // default from to a old date if it is not set
  to = to || '2999-12-31';

  var dateFrom = moment(from);
  var dateTo = moment(to);

  $('#RelatorioPorItemTable tr').each(function(i, tr) {
    var val = $(tr).find("td:nth-child(6)").text();
    var dateVal = moment(val, "DD/MM/YYYY");
    var visible = (dateVal.isBetween(dateFrom, dateTo, null, [])) ? "" : "none" ; // [] for inclusive
    $(tr).css('display', visible);

// setTimeout(CalColumnHistVendas, 1000);

  });

}

$('#datefilterfromRelatorioPorItemTable').on("change", filterRowsRelatorioPorItemTable);
$('#datefiltertoRelatorioPorItemTable').on("change", filterRowsRelatorioPorItemTable);
```

```html
  
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
   <div class="row">

            <span>INICIAL</span>
            <input type="date"  id="datefilterfromRelatorioPorItemTable" data-date-split-input="true">

            <span>FINAL</span>
          <input type="date"  id="datefiltertoRelatorioPorItemTable" data-date-split-input="true">
             <span>Position</span>
          <input type="text"  id="PositionfiltertoRelatorioPorItemTable" >
        </div>
        

    <br><br>


     <table id="RelatorioPorItemTable" class="order-table table dark3Dtable">
            <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Price</th>
               <th>date</th>
          </tr>
            </thead>

          <tr>
            <td>John Doe</td>
            <td>john.doe@gmail.com</td>
             <td>Manager</td>
            <td>0123456789</td>
            <td>99.80</td>
            <td>15/02/2020</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Jane Vanda</td>
            <td>jane@vanda.org</td>
            <td>Helper</td>
            <td>9876543210</td>
            <td>349.51</td>
            <td>19/02/2020</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Marth Johnson</td>
            <td>Marth@batman.com</td>
            <td>Free lance</td>
            <td>6754328901</td>
            <td>500.50</td>
            <td>18/02/2020</td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>Alferd Penyworth</td>
            <td>alfred@batman.com</td>
            <td>Helper</td>
            <td>6754328901</td>
            <td>199.00</td>
            <td>25/05/2020</td>
          </tr>
                    <tr>
            <td>Segio Smith</td>
            <td>Segio@gmail.com</td>
            <td>Free lance</td>
            <td>6754328901</td>
            <td>300.00</td>
            <td>19/02/2020</td>
          </tr>

      </table>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could just add plain JS to do position filtering regardless of your date Jquery filter..

**EDIT:**

On user remark in comment I edited this to position filter to only filter results from first date filter.

When doing filter by date also add a class `none`;

```
$(tr).css('display', visible);
```

changed to:

```
$(tr).css('display', visible).addClass(visible);
```

And now when selecting the `tr` tag for position search filter only `tr` tag that does not have `none` class:

```
tr = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

Change to:

```
tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.none)');
```

Now position filter works only on first result set as well as if dates are not entered...

**Example with console.log:**

```js
function filterRowsRelatorioPorItemTable() {

  var from = $('#datefilterfromRelatorioPorItemTable').val();
  var to = $('#datefiltertoRelatorioPorItemTable').val();
  

  if (!from && !to) { // no value for from and to
    return;
 
  }

  from = from || '2020-01-01'; // default from to a old date if it is not set
  to = to || '2999-12-31';

  var dateFrom = moment(from);
  var dateTo = moment(to);

  $('#RelatorioPorItemTable tr').each(function(i, tr) {
    var val = $(tr).find("td:nth-child(6)").text();
    var dateVal = moment(val, "DD/MM/YYYY");
    var visible = (dateVal.isBetween(dateFrom, dateTo, null, [])) ? "" : "none" ; // [] for inclusive
    $(tr).css('display', visible).addClass(visible);

// setTimeout(CalColumnHistVendas, 1000);

  });

}

$('#datefilterfromRelatorioPorItemTable').on("change", filterRowsRelatorioPorItemTable);
$('#datefiltertoRelatorioPorItemTable').on("change", filterRowsRelatorioPorItemTable);

function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("PositionfiltertoRelatorioPorItemTable");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("RelatorioPorItemTable");
  
  tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.none)');
  console.log(tr);
  
  
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
   <div class="row">

            <span>INICIAL</span>
            <input type="date"  id="datefilterfromRelatorioPorItemTable" data-date-split-input="true">

            <span>FINAL</span>
          <input type="date"  id="datefiltertoRelatorioPorItemTable" data-date-split-input="true">
             <span>Position</span>
          <input type="text"  id="PositionfiltertoRelatorioPorItemTable" onkeyup="myFunction()">
        </div>
        

    <br><br>


     <table id="RelatorioPorItemTable" class="order-table table dark3Dtable">
            <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Price</th>
               <th>date</th>
          </tr>
            </thead>

          <tr>
            <td>John Doe</td>
            <td>john.doe@gmail.com</td>
             <td>Manager</td>
            <td>0123456789</td>
            <td>99.80</td>
            <td>15/02/2020</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Jane Vanda</td>
            <td>jane@vanda.org</td>
            <td>Helper</td>
            <td>9876543210</td>
            <td>349.51</td>
            <td>19/02/2020</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Marth Johnson</td>
            <td>Marth@batman.com</td>
            <td>Free lance</td>
            <td>6754328901</td>
            <td>500.50</td>
            <td>18/02/2020</td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>Alferd Penyworth</td>
            <td>alfred@batman.com</td>
            <td>Helper</td>
            <td>6754328901</td>
            <td>199.00</td>
            <td>25/05/2020</td>
          </tr>
                    <tr>
            <td>Segio Smith</td>
            <td>Segio@gmail.com</td>
            <td>Free lance</td>
            <td>6754328901</td>
            <td>300.00</td>
            <td>19/02/2020</td>
          </tr>

      </table>
```

**Example:**

```js
function filterRowsRelatorioPorItemTable() {

  var from = $('#datefilterfromRelatorioPorItemTable').val();
  var to = $('#datefiltertoRelatorioPorItemTable').val();
  

  if (!from && !to) { // no value for from and to
    return;
 
  }

  from = from || '2020-01-01'; // default from to a old date if it is not set
  to = to || '2999-12-31';

  var dateFrom = moment(from);
  var dateTo = moment(to);

  $('#RelatorioPorItemTable tr').each(function(i, tr) {
    var val = $(tr).find("td:nth-child(6)").text();
    var dateVal = moment(val, "DD/MM/YYYY");
    var visible = (dateVal.isBetween(dateFrom, dateTo, null, [])) ? "" : "none" ; // [] for inclusive
    $(tr).css('display', visible).addClass(visible);

// setTimeout(CalColumnHistVendas, 1000);

  });

}

$('#datefilterfromRelatorioPorItemTable').on("change", filterRowsRelatorioPorItemTable);
$('#datefiltertoRelatorioPorItemTable').on("change", filterRowsRelatorioPorItemTable);

function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("PositionfiltertoRelatorioPorItemTable");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("RelatorioPorItemTable");
  
  tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.none)');
  //console.log(tr);
  
  
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
   <div class="row">

            <span>INICIAL</span>
            <input type="date"  id="datefilterfromRelatorioPorItemTable" data-date-split-input="true">

            <span>FINAL</span>
          <input type="date"  id="datefiltertoRelatorioPorItemTable" data-date-split-input="true">
             <span>Position</span>
          <input type="text"  id="PositionfiltertoRelatorioPorItemTable" onkeyup="myFunction()">
        </div>
        

    <br><br>


     <table id="RelatorioPorItemTable" class="order-table table dark3Dtable">
            <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Price</th>
               <th>date</th>
          </tr>
            </thead>

          <tr>
            <td>John Doe</td>
            <td>john.doe@gmail.com</td>
             <td>Manager</td>
            <td>0123456789</td>
            <td>99.80</td>
            <td>15/02/2020</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Jane Vanda</td>
            <td>jane@vanda.org</td>
            <td>Helper</td>
            <td>9876543210</td>
            <td>349.51</td>
            <td>19/02/2020</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Marth Johnson</td>
            <td>Marth@batman.com</td>
            <td>Free lance</td>
            <td>6754328901</td>
            <td>500.50</td>
            <td>18/02/2020</td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>Alferd Penyworth</td>
            <td>alfred@batman.com</td>
            <td>Helper</td>
            <td>6754328901</td>
            <td>199.00</td>
            <td>25/05/2020</td>
          </tr>
                    <tr>
            <td>Segio Smith</td>
            <td>Segio@gmail.com</td>
            <td>Free lance</td>
            <td>6754328901</td>
            <td>300.00</td>
            <td>19/02/2020</td>
          </tr>

      </table>
```

[How TO - Filter/Search Table](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp)

Comment: Hi. The problem is that after the first filters(INCIAL and FINAL) are applied the second filter looks at the entire the table. I like the second filter to only consider the visible row after the first filters are applied, ignoring the filtered out data.